# CSS is blank on site hosted by gh-pages

Tags: css, github, github-pages

It seems my CSS has been deleted from my gh-pages but when I check my GitHub repo the CSS is there.  What did I do for this to happen?

Comment: check the css link tag's href again

Comment: Here is the link <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"> is there something i need to add in the href?

Comment: okay. I hope there is css folder containing styles.css file. Just open firebug and go to net panel, see if you are getting any error like "Resource not found" ?

Comment: this is what i am getting: GET http://dtrinh888.github.io/shopping-list/css/styles.css in the console on developers tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the folder structure. Html resource are case sensitive. Please change from css/styles.css to CSS/styles.css in the link tag href attribute.

The folder you created is "CSS" not "css".

Comment: That was it! Thanks for helping me with that.